# Zend Framework: Escaping form input using setFromArray()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, sql-injection, zend-db

I've been looking at increasing security and stability across some of my websites and one thing I've been checking is escaping all input from users (as I should be doing).

In a lot of cases, I'm using the standard Zend_Db_Table_Row setFromArray() method, i.e.

```
$myForm = new Form_MyForm();
$myTable = new Model_DbTable_MyTable();

if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
{
    if ($myForm->isValid($_POST))
    {
        $myRow = $myTable->createRow();
        $myRow->setFromArray($_POST);
        $myRow->save();
    }
}
```

This works fine, as expected. However I'm not aware if the input is escaped at any point of this code (like all input from a user should be before being put anywhere near the database).  I use quoteInto() in Zend, but also use mysqli_real_escape_string() externally.

Does anyone know if the user input is escaped in the above example (ready for the DB), and if not, how do I escape it if I want to continue using the setFromArray() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setFromArray is not filtering the variables. Use

```
$form->getValues() ; // not directly the $_POST
```

This will filter/validate according to your form rules.

Other options are filter_var manually the POST or Zend_Filter.

setFromArray() just populates the row object with values, and the save() is not doing validation checks, it does an update. So you should do the escaping/validation before that and is not automatic. you can add a filter to the form itself and then use getFiltredValues/getUnfilteredValues. The only automatic escaping I think happens when using Zend_Select and you bind parameters with ?

Comment: Thanks Elzo, I just put that example together quickly but will make a note to use getValues() in all instances. The question still remains though: is the input from users is escaped automatically (different from validation). I understand filters can do some of this, but does this mean I have to add a filter to every input to block from injection attacks?

Comment: setFromArray() just populates the row object with values, and the save() is not doing validation checks, it does an update. So you should do the escaping/validation before that and is not automatic. you can add a filter to the form itself and then use getFiltredValues/getUnfilteredValues. The only automatic escaping I think happens when using Zend_Select and you bind parameters with ?

Comment: Wow, thanks Elzo, marking your answer as correct for me. I'm surprised none of the examples I've seen online for saving forms to database via. setFromArray() show any data escaping.

Comment: the examples are made to explain only 1 point at the time and not the real complexities of the real world.

Comment: @elzo your comment above is much more explanatory than your answer and should be edited into it to make it excellent :)